# Bootstrap nav pill left and right padding are not equal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a container with 2 tabs using nav-pills in bootstrap. However the gap (white space on the left hand side of the button) is not equal to the gap on the right hand side of the button. I have not added any special padding either.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0">
<div class="container">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="width:96%;">
   <li class="active" style="width:48%; text-align: center;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li style="width:48%; text-align: center;"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `margin:0  auto;` to the `.nav-pills` element. The `.nav-pills` has `width:96%;` so it is aligned to the left side of `.container`. By using `margin:0  auto;`, the `.nav-pills` is centered horizontally.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpysuymv/)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0">
<div class="container">
 //Add margin:0  auto;
 <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="width:96%;margin:0  auto;">
   <li class="active" style="width:48%; text-align: center;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li style="width:48%; text-align: center;"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: @user1692342 Does it fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nav-justified](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js) for this and then just adjust the display rule for under 768px in case you don't want them to stack.

See working Example Snippet.

```css
/**BORDER FOR DEMO ONLY*/

.nav.nav-justified {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/**BORDER FOR DEMO ONLY*/

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-justified.nav-pills-nav > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .nav-justified.nav-pills-nav > li > a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h3>Won't stack on Mobile</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified nav-pills-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Default: Will stack on Mobile</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```